# get array value from array in php

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have an array in array, and I want to get user_id from there to set to condition. I have tried everything, didn't succeed it. Please help. Thanks in Advance

```
<?php $post_user_obj = array('PostLike' => $post['PostLikesArray']); ?>

Array
(
[PostLike] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 47
                [post_id] => 109
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 62
                [post_id] => 109
            )

    )

 )


<?php if((array_search($id, array_column($post_user_obj, 'user_id')))): ?> 

<?php if(($id == $post_user_obj['PostLike']['user_id'])): ?>
```

Comment: both user_id's or just one based on something or ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the parent array index.  Such as:

`$id = $post_user_obj['Postlike'][0]['user_id'];`

Or to list them all

```
foreach ($post_user_obj['PostLike'] as $this_user){
    $id = $this_user['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, if this is the case, then I need to create array for ids, cause I wanna match <?php if((array_key_exists($id, $usres_likes_id))): ?> that ID from an "ids" array. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

An array with arrays in it is called a multidimensional array.

You can iterate through the array using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Then loop through the children arrays again using another foreach. Example:

```
$PostLike = array(array('user_id' => 47, 'post_id' => 109), array('user_id' => 62, 'post_id'=> 109));
foreach($PostLike as $subarray) {
     foreach($subarray as $name => $value) {
              if ($name == 'user_id') {
                echo $value . "\n";
         }

     }

}
```

Output:

```
47
62
```

Demo: https://eval.in/454992

If you wanted to search for a particular value you could do:

```
$PostLike = array(array('user_id' => 47, 'post_id' => 109), array('user_id' => 62, 'post_id'=> 109));
$key = array_search(62, array_column($PostLike, 'user_id'));
if($key !== false){
      echo $PostLike[$key]['user_id'];
} else {
      echo 'not present';
}
```

Output:

```
62
```

Comment: Thank you for response, if this is the case, then I need to create array for ids, cause I wanna match <?php if((array_key_exists($id, $usres_likes_id))): ?> that ID from an "ids" array. Any clue?

Comment: In your current code are you trying to find if a specific id (`47` for instance) is present in the array?

Comment: OK, in my case it creates the arrayArray([user_id] => 47 [post_id] => 107), but it gives array to every post, and I can't make it condition to work for every post, and every post is different, (kind of a "like unlike" system I'm implementing on my site)

Comment: Your array isn't structured like the one I've posted?

Comment: yes, hi, I tried, no results I get "Call to undefined function array_column()"

Comment: What PHP version are you running? If < 5.5 try looking at https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php... from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php under the `See Also` section

Comment: @XachKaa no luck with that?

Comment: @XachKaa issues, questions?